# JavaScript pausing and resuming animation google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, timer, settimeout

I am trying to pause **Google Maps** markers from animating when elements pushed into an array reaches a certain number. I have tried to clearing the timer and resuming it however i am having some problems.

I have used *console.log()* to see where control is accessing however the only message i am getting from *console.log()* is ***'500 records saved'***. The timer gets cleared however control does not access the else condition of the block to resume the timer.

I have also looked at the SO question [Pause and play google map marker animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363217/pause-and-play-google-map-marker-animation)
However i am not using buttons to pause and play.

Here is the code any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

**Console.log()**
*'500 records saved'* and animation stops does not resume

```
var lastVertex = 1;
var stepnum=0;
var step = 90; //0.9 metres
var tick = 100; // milliseconds
var eol = [];
```

**StartAnimation**

```
function startAnimation(index) {
        if (timerHandle[index]) clearTimeout(timerHandle[index]);
          eol[index]=polyline[index].Distance();
          map.setCenter(polyline[index].getPath().getAt(0));

          poly2[index] = new google.maps.Polyline({path: [polyline[index].getPath().getAt(0)], strokeColor:"#FFFF00", strokeWeight:3});

          timerHandle[index] = setTimeout("animate("+index+",50)",2000);  // Allow time for the initial map display         

  }
```

**Animate**

```
function animate(index,d) {  

       if (d>eol[index]) {

        marker[index].setPosition(endLocation[index].latlng);       

        if(marker[index].getPosition() == endLocation[index].latlng){
            console.log('Completed'+' '+index);
        }  


        return;
     }

         var p = polyline[index].GetPointAtDistance(d);
         marker[index].setPosition(p);
         updatePoly(index,d);

         timerHandle[index] = setTimeout("animate("+index+","+(d+step)+")", tick);

         citizens1.push({lat:marker[index].getPosition().lat(),lng:marker[index].getPosition().lng(),socialSecurityNumber:global_citizens[index].socialSecurityNumber});

         if(citizens1.length = 500){             
             console.log('500 records saved');          
             window.clearTimeout( timerHandle[index]);       
             citizens1 = []; //clear the array
         }

  }
```

Comment: if(citizens1.length = 500){ /***NOTE THE SINGLE '=' SHOULD BE '==', Also I don't see any 'else' condition you are referring to***/

Comment: I removed the else since it was not necessary however i am expecting control to access timerHandler at the top again once citizens1 = []